# Regarding a byte condition

Tags: java

I am stuck in an issue.  I have the following method:

```
public byte determineCardType(final IInput inputData) {
    byte cardType = UNKNOWN_CARD;
    try {
      if (isWagRewardsLoyaltyCard(inputData))
        cardType = WAG_LOYALTY_CARD_TYPE;
      else if (isDRCard(inputData))   //checking that card scanned and swiped is a DR Card
        cardType = DR_CARD_TYPE;      
           else if (isWagRewardsPartnerCard(inputData))
        cardType = AARP_CARD_TYPE;
      return cardType;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return UNKNOWN_CARD;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, I have another piece of code in which I am checking the card type that is returned from the above method.

```
if((aarpCardSupport.isAARPCard(input))||(determineCardType(input)==DR_CARD_TYPE))  
        {
        return true;
        }else if((isDRCard(input))&&(isDRLoayltyEnabled())) //would return 1 for DR card only when isDRLoayltyEnabled returns true 
        {
          return true;
        }       
        return false ;  
}
```

But in the above code as shown determinecardtype is showing an error since it's return type is byte and I cannot compare using

```
if((aarpCardSupport.isAARPCard(input))||(determineCardType(input)==DR_CARD_TYPE))  ,
```

Please advise.

Comment: which error? what is the type of constants in uppercase?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (aarpCardSupport.isAARPCard(input)
    || determineCardType(input) == (byte)DR_CARD_TYPE)
```

Or have

```
public static final byte DR_CARD_TYPE = (byte) -2;
// Byte is signed, hence 254 = 256 - 2.
```

---

***Second attempt:***

Assuming that DR_CARD_TYPE is both an `int` and maybe in the range 128-255, try:

```
if (aarpCardSupport.isAARPCard(input)
    || ((int)determineCardType(input)) & 0xFF == DR_CARD_TYPE & 0xFF)
```

Unlikely though. Maybe the error lies (elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using byte values you can't use not logic 'and' `&&` or 'or' `||`. If you want to use bitwise 'and' or 'or' operators you need to use `&` and `|` respectively.